# Do passive auras like Sona's grant assists?

Tags: league-of-legends

If Sona grants an aura to an ally that gets a kill, will this count as an assist?  I'm assuming she hasn't changed her auras during the fight.

Do items that grant auras act the same way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the LoL wiki [here](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Assist) Assists are granted when someone ACTIVELY does something to help for the kill. Healing counts, but passive auras do not. If they did I would think Janna would have infinite assists because of her passive. I believe this is also including things such as Aegis and Life steal auras don't count.

Comment: I was wrong, actually. I had been thinking Sona gets assists, but it's only because of the activation of her W and E. So even if she can't sneak in a hit with Q, it'd be the active buffs from her auras, and not the passive benefit. This generally translates to Sona always getting an assist when present (because you should be using those active buffs), but not because of the aura alone.

Comment: @GraceNote Yeah, completley passive abilities that can't be toggled wouldn't count towards assists. That would just be cheap.

Comment: From your source: "Additionally, assists can be scored by passively supporting a champion that contributed to the kill, e.g. by healing an allied champion."  That seems to contradict your answer.

Comment: Well, ones like Janna, Zilean, and Twisted Fate that are global, those would indeed be ridiculous. But an effect that requires you to be in the battle, whether you land a hit or not, one could almost consider that being a proper assist (especially, some auras can be life-saving). Mechanically, though, it doesn't play out that way.

Comment: @Toast As long as the healing is done ACTIVLEY (Heal, Wish, Janna's heal) And not passivley (Providing an aura that gives lifesteal)

Comment: @Toast "passively supporting" and "e.g. by healing" are contradictory. If you're healing, that's not passive.

Comment: @Raven, think of Zekes aka Starks or Emblem of Valor.  Passive healing.  I agree the wording of the quote is misleading.

Comment: @Toast Neither HP / 5 nor Lifesteal is counted as healing by the game.

Comment: Where would you draw the line? I am technically assisting my team by drawing the other teams attention to the other part of the map so they can go stomp on a carry :)

Comment: @James, a conversation like that sparked this question: should detecting an invis champion count for an assist?